# Bayes and Naive Bayes code implementations

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes, scalability

I know that Bayes classifier assigns the new data point $\pmb{x}$ to the class $\omega_j, \ j=1,\dots,M$, when

$p(\omega_j \mid \pmb{x}) = \max_{q=1,\dots,M}p(\omega_q \mid \pmb{x})$,

where

$p(\omega_j\mid \pmb{x}) = \frac{p(\pmb{x}\mid \omega_j)p(\omega_j)}{p(\pmb{x})} = \frac{p(\pmb{x}\mid \omega_j)p(\omega_j)}{\sum_j p(\pmb{x} \mid \omega_j)p(\omega_j)}$.

The difference from the Naive Bayes classifier is that Naive Bayes assumes statistical independent features,

$p(\pmb{x}|\omega_j) = \prod_{k=1}^{l}p_k(x_k|\omega_j), \ \ \ \ \ j=1,\dots,M$

where $l$ is the number of features.

Why there are only Naive Bayes classifier implementations and there are not the full Bayes ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, Naive Bayes assumes conditional independence of features (conditioned on classes), not statistical independence. And, informally speaking, despite strong assumptions, it works pretty ok in practice. An obvious reason of using *naive* assumption is that the number of parameters needed in the model is *linear* with increasing number of features. Imagine that $p(\mathbf{x}|w_i)$ is Gaussian and you need the covariance matrix to characterize the Bayes classifier, and $\mathbf{x}$ is high dimensional, like $R^{10000}$, like in spam classification problem, e.g. the size of the vocabulary set. Then, the covariance matrix would have $10^8$ entries to be learnt. This isn't scalable. Or using non-parametric methods (like KDE) for joint PDF estimation would need immense amount of data.